# Whether to create a custom exception or wait to occur NullReferenceException down the line?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am confused. Whether to create a custom exception or .Net base class library has the relevant exception?

I am calling some kind of service or framework API and it returns back a null reference which is an exceptional case for my tier. I know that the system won't be able to proceed with null reference and I should get a NullReferenceException down the line if I proceed.

So, should I create a custom exception at that point or should I wait to occur the NullPointerReference?

See the code snippet below

```
Organization organization = OrganizationService.GetOrganizationById("123");
this.SetOrders(organization.Id); // This will give me NullReferenceException
```

please guide me.

Thanks and regards

123Developer

Answer (score 3):

In general, its good practice to catch errors as soon as possible and handle them in the best manner possible - either by using default values to work around the error, or informing the user that you cannot proceed.

So in this specific case, if i understand correctly, i would test the variable for null, and if its null do not continue - bail out gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

*NullPointerReference* exceptions are always hard to debug and should be avoided whenever possible. In certain cases you could use *ArgumentNullException*, if the "null" value is one of the passed parameters. Not in your case though and that's where I would recommend a custom exception.

Answer (score 2):

Throw an `InvalidOperationException` if it has nothing to do with any arguments passed to your method, or an `ArgumentException` otherwise. Do this as soon as is reasonably possible, to avoid accidentally corrupting your state.

Aside from anything else, this allows you to give a more useful message, indicating what couldn't be found.

Answer (score 2):

as a general rule you should only catch exceptions down the stack if you can add meaning to the exception itself.

In your particular case, I would suggest that you check the value for `null`, and throw an appropriate exception yourself (possibly an `InvalidOperationException` with a message of "Organization not found"?)

Answer (score 1):

I often design a DataNotFoundException that is thrown when a get-operation based on an object ID fails. My rationale for doing so is that ID's are typically not entered by the user, but used only in the code, so if a search is performed using a non-existing ID the input is bad, and I want to signal that in a clear manner.